# How to compute the tensor multiplier from an image transformation?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Firstly, I assume people are familiar with Python [numpy.tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html). Here I use a simple instance of that as follows (pseudocode):

```
A.shape = (1, x, y)
B.shape = (x, y, z, t)
C = numpy.tensordot(A, B)
C.shape = (1, z, t)
```

Now imagine A and C above are greyscale images (1 channel), and there is an image transformation that turns A into C. To be specific, assume people are familiar with OpenCV in Python and the functions [cv2.warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine) and [cv2.warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective), let's (pseudocode):

```
C = cv2.warpSomething(A, **kwargs)
```

My question is that, assume the above equations hold, then how to compute B (efficiently enough) from the variables (pseudocode):

```
x, y, z, t, the_transformation (i.e. warpAffine or warpPerspective, M, flags, borderMode, borderValue)
```

I'm also satisfied if one can produce B from only (warp, x, y, z, t, M), fixing flags=INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT and borderValue=0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If there are `N` pixels in both A and C, then the transformation tensor B has `N**2` components. For `N` on the order of 1E+6, you really don't want to store the B tensor. If it's a very small dataset, you could try something like this:

```
# assuming C and A are already initialized.
B = np.zeros(A.shape + C.shape)
A1 = np.zeros_like(A)
for i in range(A1.shape[0]):
   for j in range(A1.shape[1]):
       A1[i, j] = 1
       B[i, j, :, :] = affine_something(A1)
       A1[i, j] = 0
```

But this is still very slow and inefficient.